# Is H4 the correct visa to use after relatives have become green card holders?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens

I am looking into staying with my relatives in the USA (I live in the UK). They were originally using a H1-B visa but now have green card status. If I want to go and stay with them, is applying for a H4 visa the correct choice?

Comment: No. You apply for a visitors visa. You are not eligible for H4 unless you are a child or wife of an H1B. And you cannot stay for a year nor work in the USA on a visitor visa. You need to learn more about USA visas and immigration.

Comment: If you want to explore your options for working in the USA, our sister site [expatriates.se] may be able to help. But be aware that it is very difficult to get a USA visa that permits working.

Comment: @kumikan What is your citizenship? Be aware that the US starts from a position of assuming immigrant intent, planning to stay for a year will reinforce that assumption (leaving aside your thoughts on working, which is not permitted as a visitor, as others have already commented).

Comment: @Traveller I am a UK citizen.

Comment: @kumikan The simple fact is you **cannot** work in the US as a visitor; you need to secure employment in advance and the employer will need to sponsor you, proving no US workers qualify for the job you're seeking. Then you'll apply for and obtain an H1/H2 visa.

Comment: @kumikan However, if you have finances to support yourself, along with substantial ties to the UK, and can document this, you can get a B visa and apply (at the border) to enter for a year. You cannot work during your stay though